# smallest positive definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Given positive (semi) definite matrices A and B, can we answer the question, what is Max c s.t. A - cB is positive (semi) definite for scalar c? In other words,
\begin{align}
\max_{c\in \mathbb{R}}~c \\
\text{subject to }A-cB>=0
\end{align}

Are there useful results to help a line search?

Comment: I don't really understand the question, but I feel like [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalEquation.html) is related.

Comment: Well, at least we know that the optimal $c$ must be nonnegative, and sine the diagonal of $A-cB$ has to be nonnegative, you can narrow down the range of $c$ a bit.

Answer (score 3):

Good News: Your question is well studied. 
(not so) bad news: There is no closed form solution in general.

Note that $A-cB$ is positive (semi) definite for $c=0$, thus $0$ is a lower bound. Define $F=A-cB$. Let $\lambda_{min}(.)$ denote the minimum eigenvalue of its argument.

**Closed Form Solution**-- A closed form solution exists whenever $B$ is invertible and in that case, $c=\lambda_{min}(B^{-1}A)$. (please try on your own to prove it.)

**Iterative Solution**-- Whenever $B$ is not invertible, you will need resort to some other technique. The key observation here is that your problem is convex and belongs to the class of ***semi-definite programming***. Thus, any standard convex package, for eg: CVX (search google), should be able to solve it. If you are insistent over a custom line search algorithm, make the observation that the one dimensional function $f(c)$, defined as
\begin{align}
f(c)=\lambda_{min}(A-cB)
\end{align}
is concave function of $c$ over the real line. It is monotonically non-increasing function of $c$, if one restricts it to the non-negative values for $c$, which is the interesting range for you. Note that $f(0)\geq 0$ Thus, you are interested in the point where $f(c)$ crosses the $x-axis$, thus the standard bisection algorithm [given here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method)l will definitely help. It basically finds the zero-crossing point of the input function which is you what you need here.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the thorough response. I don't follow the closed form solution though: We already know that c = 0 is a lower bound. But there is no guarantee that B^{-1}A is positive semi-definite, is there? Tried to prove it myself but arriving at the given answer seems to rely on A and B^{-1} commuting, which is not given.

Comment: If $B$ is invertible (hence positive definite), let $B^{1/2}$ be its (unique) positive definite square root. Hence $A-cB\ge0$ is equivalent to $B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2}-cI\ge0$, and the maximum $c$ is given by $\lambda_\min(B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2})=\lambda_\min(B^{-1}A)$.

Comment: @user1551 I thought one could directly multiply $B^{-1}$ on both sides of $A-cB\geq 0$ to conclude that, why isn't it possible?

Comment: @dineshdileep This is because $B^{-1}A-cI$ is not necessarily Hermitian, so technically we can't speak of its +ve semidefiniteness. But surely this is just a minor issue. After all, we are only interested in the eigenvalues.

Comment: $B^{-1}$ is positive definite, $A$ is positive semi-definite, so their product should be positive semi-definite? does that argument work?